# Handle callbacks in my library

Tags: android, callback, android-volley, android-library, aar

I have written an android library that does network calls to various websites and returns the necessary content. I am using Volley library which has callbacks like `onResponse` and `onFailure`. Initially this library was an app and was later changed to an library.

When it was an app I could handle the callbacks easily. Whenever the callback happens I call the required functions from there but now when I import as the library and try to use it the control returns from the library as soon as I call it and the call back is not doing anything.

```
public void sendForVerification(final String Response, final String Secret, final String Name) {
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            flag = true;
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error){
                flag = false;
            }
        }})  {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams () throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("secret", Secret);
                params.put("response", Response);
                return params;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

When this code was a part of the app instead of returning the flag value I would call an appropriate function to handle the result. Now whenever I call these functions the value of flag is returned before the callback is done and this is causing some problem.

My question is how can I warp this around a callback so that the app that uses this library will be notified when the network call is done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add your own callback(s) for your library

```
interface YourCallback<T> {
    onResponse(T value);
}
```

---

```
public void sendForVerification(final String Response,final String Secret,final String Name, YourCallback<Boolean> callback){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            callback.onResponse(true);
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            callback.onResponse(false);
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("secret",Secret);
            params.put("response",Response);
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

---

```
boolean flag;

api.sendForVerification("", "", "", new YourCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Boolean value) {
        flag = value;
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this will work for the `Volley` library but I also have other Google API's that perform calls. what should I do for that? Is there any generalised callback that I can create in my library and call them from the app whenever needed.

Comment: Personally, I don't think it's a good pattern to combine the error and success callbacks, but the interface definition is up to you

Answer (score 0):

Volley is asynchronus, so any other upcoming process after you send the request will continue as normal without waiting for a response. That's why your flag value seems like it hasn't changed, because you probably try to access it while the request is still waiting for a response. That's the reason of callback implementations: you take certain actions as soon as you get a response, and you shouldn't try to handle values that will be returned from another method, because they will be returned before they change.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't figure it out at first later after the answer by @cricket_007 I was able to implement my own callback and make it work.